# What's an adjective that means "has high expectations"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adjectives, vocabulary

If you were to describe a person as someone who has high expectations or standards (of their work, peers, or subordinates), what word would you use?

"Demanding" is the closest I have come but that's not quite correct. That leads to words like "stringent" and "exacting" which also aren't what I'm looking for.

Context: the classic resume word-choice struggle

As always, when nothing comes to mind I'm tempted to head back to the drawing board. Resume writing is such a silly exercise.

Comment: Exigent, may well be another option.

Comment: While not quite the same as what you asked in the strictest of sense, **methodical** is a positive word for a resumé that would go well with the answer to this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like saying simply, "I have **high standards** for myself and teammates."

Comment: I prefer that as well. I'd definitely take that route in an interview situation. However, I'm trying to remain as concise as possible on paper.

Comment: The words already suggested are good if you are a writer but putting them on a resume could make you appear borderline OCD or at the very least, a bit pompous.

Comment: I tend to agree with that assessment.

Answer (score 3):

Consider **[punctilious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/punctilious)**

> very careful about behaving properly and doing things in a correct and accurate way

Also consider

- [meticulous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/meticulous)
- [scrupulous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/scrupulous)
- [painstaking](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/painstaking)
- [conscientious](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/conscientious)

Comment: +1 back at ya. These are all positive connotations. Much nicer to say you're meticulous or painstaking, while your detractors are saying you're anal or picky.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're *meticulous*.

[Meticulous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meticulous): very careful about doing something in an extremely accurate and exact way

Answer (score 2):

Consider **particular**.

*He is very **particular** about his grades and working hard.*

Answer (score 1):

You could use 'principled' in this context in that you have exacting principles.

'Uncompromising' also comes to mind, although you'd be careful using that on a resume so people don't think you're hard to work with.

Comment: Haha. That's the issue I've been having with many of the potential choices here. I'm either specific in my wording or I'm a hard ass.

Comment: I usually use 'detail oriented' or 'attention to details' to cover this case. If you notice details chances are you also have high standards.

Answer (score 1):

Aspirational

Having or characterized by aspirations to achieve social prestige and material success:

Comment: Makes it sound like I'm breathing something I shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the adjective "challenging," as in [an authoritarian boss that has high demands is a challenging employer.](http://www.workplaceviolence.ca/resource-library/articles/bully-boardroom)

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/challenging